# R Shiny InsertUI into fluidRow

Tags: r, shiny

I want to be able to remove a UI element, which is a textInput contained in a fluidRow and re-insert that element (fluidRow and textInput) back into the UI. However, so far I'm not having any success.

The removeUI button removed all fluidRows including those in which the buttons are found. If I try and put them in a separate HTML division it seems to make little difference. Or if it works the textInput is no longer in an offset fluid row. This is my first shiny question so please be gentle I may have made some obvious errors.

```
  # Define UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
          fluidRow(column(2,actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"))),
          fluidRow(column(2,actionButton("add", "Add UI"))),
          tags$div(id='aTextBox', fluidRow(column(2,offset=6,
                                                  textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful"))
                                            )
                                   )
)


   # Server logic
 server <- function(input, output) {

   observeEvent(input$rmv, {
       removeUI(
         selector = "div:has(> #aTextBox)"
      )
    })

   observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
       where = "afterEnd",
       ui = tags$div(id='aTextBox', fluidRow(column(2,offset=6,
                                               textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful"))
                                        )
                                )
     )
   })
 }

   # Complete app with UI and server components
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the div in both places with:

```
  tags$div(fluidRow(id='aTextBox', column(2,offset=6,
                                          textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful"))
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out by Barbara `div(id = "placeholder")`, can be used so that the text box is not placed into the same div as the `actionButton()`.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem there is that the removeUI is too broad. What you wanted in that case is to do directly `removeUI('#aTextBox')`.

However, there's a few issues with this code, even if it was working correctly. These mostly have to do with the fact that it allows users to hit "Add" multiple times, but this will always add the exact same element, with same id, which is invalid HTML. Most browsers won't complain about it at first, but it will come back to bite you. To solve this, you can either change the ids every time the user clicks "Add", so that there's no possibility of duplication. Or, you can keep track of whether or not that element was already inserted (but not yet removed). You can do this with a simple reactive value.  This seemed to be the behavior you were after, so I made a mock up below (this code runs fine, but it probably would benefit from some refactoring and variable renaming), with some more bells and whistles (notifications that pop up when you click "Add" or "Remove" when you shouldn't):

```r
dynamicUI <- function(n) {
  if (n != 0) {
    showNotification("That input already exists",
      type = "warning"
    )
    return()
  } else {
    fluidRow(id = 'aTextBox', 
      column(2, offset = 6,
        textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful")
      )
    )
  }
}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(2, actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"))),
  fluidRow(column(2, actionButton("add", "Add UI"))),
  div(id = "placeholder"),
  dynamicUI(0)
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  n <- reactiveVal(1)

  observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    if (n() != 1) {
      showNotification("Nothing to remove",
        type = "error"
      )
      return()
    }
    removeUI(selector = "#aTextBox")
    n(0)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = dynamicUI(n())
    )
    n(1)
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```